# 18.04 LTS - Fourth button on titlebar

Tags: icons, themes, appearance, titlebar

I have suffered this weird button for a few days. It is really annoying to use customized icon themes (default one is fine).

Does anyone know what this is? I want to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to get into `dconf` and see this configuration. Question solved.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify? Did you reset it to the default value?

Comment: Yep. It's been illuminated on the image.

Answer (score 2):

Result of

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout
```

should be 'appmenu:minimize,maximize,close'

if not

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout appmenu:minimize,maximize,close
```